# Material UI Popover - keydown event simulation issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, material-ui, keyevent

The task is to navigate in a dropdown list via arrow keys instead of TAB/TAB+SHIFT. One of the ideas was to replace key down events of arrow keys to simulate TAB/TAB+SHIFT key down. My approach comes down to the code below, which successfully prevents default arrow keys events and triggers code for TAB key showing the alert.

Unfortunately, it doesn't move the highlight to desired list item and besides triggering TAB key event on paper does nothing.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
handleKeyDown = (e) => {
let element  = e.currentTarget;

switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 40:
  e.preventDefault();
  const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 9, shiftKey: false });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  break;
}
switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 38:
  e.preventDefault();
  const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 9, shiftKey: true });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  break;
}

// the switch case 9 is only used for debugging purposes
     switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 9:
          e.preventDefault();
          alert ("You pressed the 'TAB' key!");
          break;
        }

<Popover onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
```

Comment: on which element are you trying to navigate?

Comment: First things first, if you want to handle different cases, handle with a single switch statement, like follows:

`switch (e.keycode) {
    case 40:
        // code\n
    case 38:
        // code\n
    case 9:
        // code\n
}`

Comment: @Toumash On the input field and the list of elements of the dropdown list - exactly like the TAB/TAB+SHIFT works currently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling the `e.keycode==9` and preventing default event in this block,

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 9:
  e.preventDefault();
  alert ("You pressed the 'TAB' key!");
  break;
}
```

When you trigger key 9 when down or up is pressed in the line,

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", 
                               { view: window,
                                 bubbles: true,
                                 cancelable: true,
                                 keyCode: 9,
                                 shiftKey: true });
```

You are actually triggering your block's `case 9` where `e.preventDefault()` prevents it from executing its default behavior.

The solution would be to remove `e.preventDefault()` for case 9
But when tab is pressed on that element it will also work.

Suggestion: Use a single switch with many cases as mentioned by me in the comment above. That is the right syntax for switch cases in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess I need to clarify it in the question - the code related to the switch case 9 is only to show that the code really triggers the key down event. It isn't used in the final application.

Comment: Assuming you don't have a switch case 9 block, Can you update the question and also try it out with a single switch and multiple cases

Comment: I am quite sure that switch syntax isn't a problem, I've tried it also with if statements and the results are the same - despite it triggers events for TAB key, it doesn't impact the popover list in an expected way.